# node.js tar module, 'entry' readable stream

Tags: node.js, pipe, tar

how should I use 'entry' readable stream from tar module to [pipe - npmsj.org](https://npmjs.org/package/tar) their content without get a stream error in pipe?

this is to get hint for [stream-adventure - github](https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure?source=cc) last exercise.

I'm not looking for a answer. but a hint or advice.

Here is my code:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var tar = require('tar');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var through = require('through');

var unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
var parser = tar.Parse();
var stream = process.stdin.pipe(crypto.createDecipher(process.argv[2], process.argv[3])).pipe(unzip);
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5', { encoding: 'hex' });

parser.on('entry', function(entry) {
  if (entry.type === 'File') {
    entry.pipe(md5).pipe(process.stdout);
    console.log(entry.path);
  }
});

unzip.pipe(parser);
```

here is the output:

```
$> stream-adventure run app
97911dcc607865d621029f6f927c7851
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:130:12)
    at Hash.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:178:5)
    at Entry.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Entry.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Entry._read (/home/n0t/stream-adventure/secretz/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:111:10)
    at Entry.write (/home/n0t/stream-adventure/secretz/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:68:8)
    at Parse._process (/home/n0t/stream-adventure/secretz/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:104:11)
    at BlockStream.<anonymous> (/home/n0t/stream-adventure/secretz/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:46:8)
    at BlockStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at BlockStream._emitChunk (/home/n0t/stream-adventure/secretz/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream/block-stream.js:145:10)
```

and with the `verify`:

```
$> stream-adventure verify app

ACTUAL:   "97911dcc607865d621029f6f927c7851"
EXPECTED: "97911dcc607865d621029f6f927c7851 secretz/METADATA.TXT"

ACTUAL:   null
EXPECTED: "2cdcfa9f8bbefb82fb7a894964b5c199 secretz/SPYING.TXT"

ACTUAL:   null
EXPECTED: ""

# FAIL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `entry` writes into the `md5` stream after is has been closed. Once a stream is closed, you can't write into it again: for `md5` this is easy to understand because you have to reset the internal buffers, otherwise the hash will be skewed.

In your example, on each file in the `tar` module, you pipe the file stream into the **same** md5 stream. You just have to pipe the file stream into a new MD5 stream; here is how you can do it properly:

```
parser.on('entry', function(entry) {
  if (entry.type === 'File') {
    var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5', { encoding: 'hex' });
    entry.pipe(md5).pipe(process.stdout);
    console.log(entry.path);
  }
});
```